# Integrating this complex function, using Residue Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I am having a massive amount of trouble integrating this, I really have no clue how to get the answer in the book:

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{1+x^8}dx$$

I know I need to find the poles on this function, which is basically the value of $x^8 = -1$ or I could split it up like the following:
$$x^8 +  1 = (x^4 + i)(x^4 - i)$$
With this I got the following poles (looking at $x^4 - i$), all have an order one:
\begin{array}
& x_1 = e^{\frac{i\pi}{8}} \\ x_2 = e^{\frac{3i\pi}{8}} \\ x_3 = e^{\frac{5i\pi}{8}} \\ x_4 = e^{\frac{7i\pi}{8}}
\end{array}
Now to calculate the residues I am trying to make use of the result that given a rational function $\frac{F}{G}$ such that both of them are analytic on a disk of radius $r$ with $G(z_0) = 0$ but $G'(z_0) \neq 0$ then we know that:
$$Res(\frac{F}{G};z_0) = \frac{F(z_0)}{G'(z_0)}$$
With that I am having difficulty getting results that are useful, I maybe calculating wrong and I am not sure but I have been spending a long time on this one question. The solution in the book is $\frac{\pi}{4}[sin(\frac{3\pi}{8}]^{-1}$. I would like a step by step solution to this or at least some guidance because I really need to learn this and I am not sure how to do this properly. Thank you!

Comment: You forgot an $i$ in the exponents of $x_2,x_3,x_4$. Is that a typo just here, or may that be related to your difficulties?

Comment: Oh I am sorry that was a typo I will fix that right now! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Oh wow... yeah that is the exact question. But the solutions seem to use other methods outside of the Residue Theorem.

Comment: @InsigMath Two of the three answers use the residue theorem. One of them is mine!

Comment: The other is mine.

Comment: Ahh I see ... umm I don't fully understand your solution @FlybyNight, I am not understanding where the key fact is used in the calculation. I know that once we have our residues we have to add them up, what is this stuff where you integrate from $-R$ to $R$?

Comment: I strongly recommend this video for learning about residue integration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3p_E9jZOU8  , the trick is to consider a semi circular contour with corners at $-A + 0i$ to $+A + 0i$, show that the integral along the arc is zero, and take the limit as $A \rightarrow \infty$.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem gives an example showing how to go from $x = -\infty$ to $x = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks I will look at this video now!

Comment: @InsigMath It wasn't intended to be a solution. The site's policy is to give hints to homework questions. Follow the links provided in the other answer, particularly the one for semi-circular contour it links to a worked example. The $-A$ and $+A$ in Daniel's answer are my $-R$ and $+R$.

Comment: @RonGordon I know this has been a couple opf hours but I stopped and looked at something else. I looked at your solution in the link and I sort of understand what you are doing but I don't understand why for the third integral where you went from $R$ to $0$ you chainged your variable to t and multipled it by $e^{i\pi/4}$

Comment: @InsigMath: the parametrization of that last segment of the contour is $z=e^{i \pi/4} t$.  That explains the factor.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over 1 + x^{8}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}.\quad}$
Let's take a 'pizza slice' with angle $\ds{{2\pi \over 8} = {\pi \over 4}\ \mbox{and}
\quad x_{1} = \expo{\ic\pi/8}}$

> \begin{align}
> &2\pi\ic\,{x_{1}^{4} \over 8x_{1}^{7}}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over 1 + x^{8}}\,\dd x
> +\int_{\infty}^{0}
> {r^{4}\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/4}}^{4} \over 1 + r^{8}\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/4}}^{8}}\,
> \expo{\ic\pi/4}\,\dd r
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{1 + \expo{\ic\pi/4}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over 1 + x^{8}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{4} \over 1 + x^{8}}\,\dd x}
=
2\bracks{{\pi\ic \over 4x_{1}^{3}}\,
{\expo{-\ic\pi/8} \over \expo{-\ic\pi/8} + \expo{\ic\pi/8}}}
=
{\pi\ic \over 2x_{1}^{4}}\,{1 \over 2\cos\pars{\pi/8}}
=
{\pi \over 2}\,{1 \over 2\cos\pars{\pi/8}}
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 4}\,\sec\pars{\pi \over 8}
=\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 4}\root{4 - 2\root{2}}\,\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't quite understand it ... so you are only integrating the the contour of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and go from what I imagine is $0 \to R$, then $0 \to \pi/4$ then $R \to 0$, while taking $R\to \infty$ but why are you parametizing the second integral but not the first, and how did you get the integral after the second '=' sign?

Comment: why did the i factor disappear in the last integral on the second last line?

Comment: Nevermind ... the $x^{4}_1 = i$. I got it now.